# WordPress nav menu no longer updating

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I have a WordPress site whose wp_nav_menu has stopped updating.  It can still read the menu and display it; it's just no longer possible to add new menu items of any type or to rearrange the items.  Upon saving, eventually the request will time out or return no information.

I switched to the TwentyTen theme and disabled all plugins and that had no effect.

It's still possible to publish new pages/posts, as well as edit existing ones.  Even ajax functions in other parts of the admin (like widgets) work fine.

Has anyone out there experienced this and if so, how did you correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many menu items do you have? WP sometimes has problems with large menus; it's a known bug that is being addressed http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14134

Try increasing the timeouts and memory allocation in php.ini, i.e.:

```
max_execution_time = 90
max_input_time = 300
memory_limit = 64M
```